# How to stop Google Chrome from placing a forward slash when searching for c# related questions?

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I am wondering if there is a way to stop Google Chrome from adding a forward slash by default when I am searching for c# related queries. For example if I type:

"c# how to"

as a search term in the search bar it will default the search to:

"c/# how to" which returns an error.

This happens every time I start a search term with c# so I am wondering if anyone knows how to stop this from happening? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't do it for me

Comment: This question is offtopic for this site, so you probably won't get any answers...but I just tested this on Chrome for Windows and it doesn't happen for me. However, I did notice that there IS an autocomplete entry for the "C/#" version you are talking about, but it isn't selected by default (http://i.imgur.com/kIJ3bPJ.png).

Comment: It does this sometimes for me, since a few Chrome versions. Workaround is always pressing Ctrl+E to search, which places a question mark in the address/search bar. Offtopic for SO anyway. This bug [has been reported](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409845).

Comment: Sorry I thought it would be appropriate as it only happens when I'm searching for c# related queries. It always happens to me when I search.

Comment: The problem is that it auto-selects for me and I was wondering if there is a way to stop it from auto selecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chrome that has been fixed in a recent update (Nov 4 2014) but won't be pushed out until the next minor release (which could be a month or two). You can switch to the Dev channel of Chrome and pick up the update now.

See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409845 for more details.